# excel macro or TFS add in for uploading and downloading test cases from TFS

Tags: excel, tfs, macros, tfs-2015, vba

we have a list of test cases in excel, we can change the format to support TFS.
we need to upload test case to TFS from excel, does TFS addin supports it or can we write a macro to do the job.
please do help me, below is the sample screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the View: Grid option from the Test hub of TFS web interface:
[image]
Just copy from Excel file and paste into test cases grid.

Comment: I am looking for a solution from excel though a code or addin, i am building a tool for manual & automation team where this feature is mandatory. is there any option where we can do it, For example in HP ALM we have direct option avilable to do it

Comment: Then you can use the TFS API to create the test cases: [sample](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2013/10/07/tfs-api-part-51-adding-test-step-amp-shared-step/) or you can opt to use the utility from [codeplex](http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/)

Comment: can we write TFS API in excel ?

Comment: Yes you can write an Excel add-in that is accessing the TFS API; or you can use the TFS Excel [add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181675.aspx) that comes with Team Explorer

Comment: Thanks ds 19, can you provide a sample on how to access TFS API in excel ?

Comment: i tried using TFS Excel add-in that comes with Team Explorer, it doesnt update test steps associated with test cases

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to upload test case from Excel is as @ds19 mentions, going to TFS web access, import your test cases steps by copy and save.

[image]

[Programming for the TFS Excel Add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/team_foundation/archive/2010/11/06/programming-for-the-tfs-excel-add-in.aspx) only can achieve some controls. If you don't want to use View: Grid option, the only way is to use [TFS API](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2013/10/07/tfs-api-part-51-adding-test-step-amp-shared-step/) to add test steps, or develop your own tool by following [Test Case Migrator Plus tool](http://tcmimport.codeplex.com/).